# IP Header: Total Length vs. Internet Header Length

Tags: networking, ip

I have some questions w.r.t. the ip header.

If I am correct, the total length field shows the length of the overall packet. The internet header length (ihl) shows the length of the header and whether options are set or not.

My question is why the ihl field is needed if there is the total length field that shows the total length?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With IPv4, the header length is variable. The IHL is really a pointer to the start of the packet payload. Without this, you would be unable to know where the payload starts.

IPv6 has a fixed header size, so the IHL is unnecessary, and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.